# Restricting list of billing addresses

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Taking payment using StripeCheckout.configure() & handler.open with billingAddress set to true. I'm only going to be shipping product to UK & possible some EU addresses. Is it possible to restrict the list of countries in the country drop-down to a specific set? I can check country code in token : function(token, args){} but restricting the country set would make for a better user experience.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unfortunately not something that Stripe supports today. They control the whole UI with Stripe Checkout and do not let you pass a billing address or limit the set of countries at the moment.

The best solution is to validate this after the fact or simply collect the shipping address separately from Checkout to ensure that your customers know you can only ship to specific countries.

Comment: Has this changed as of 2023?

Comment: No change for now no